# Can I now consider the range of Int to be the same as Int64 in iOS app development?

Tags: ios, swift

Swift's `Int` type has different maximum and minimum values that can be assigned, depending on whether the execution environment is 32-bit or 64-bit.

In a 32-bit execution environment, the range would be `-2_147_483_648` to `2_147_483_647`.
This is the same range as the `Int32` type.
In a 64-bit execution environment, the range is `-9_223_372_036_854_775_808` to `9_223_372_036_854_775_807`.
This is the same range as the `Int64` type.

I am currently working on an app that targets iOS 13 or later.
According to my research, all iPhones, iPod touches, and iPads that can install iOS 13 are 64-bit execution environments.
Also, Apple Silicon Macs that can run iOS apps are also 64-bit environments.

Then can I write a program that assumes that the range of type `Int` is the same as that of type `Int64`?
Specifically, can I assign values that would crash in a 32-bit environment (for example, values larger than `2_147_483_647`) to the `Int` type variables as a matter of course?
Or should I not write such a program?

(I used a translation tool to ask this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require iOS 13 and just use Ints. To assert the range of Int is the same as the range of Int64:

`assert(Int.max == Int64.max && Int.min == Int64.min)`

Answer (score 1):

> In iOS 11 and later, all apps use the 64-bit architecture.

[See also](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/updating_your_app_from_32-bit_to_64-bit_architecture).